# Regex pattern replacing in Tkinter

Tags: python, regex, tkinter

Disclosure: Code not my own just edited from internet and added Regex function.

I want to find numbers in text and replace it with 'number' tag using Regex and the following code does it. I use tkinter to get text from user.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def Reg_ex():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    A = re.sub("\d+", '<number>',inputValue)
    print(A)
textBox=Text(root, height=40, width=50)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Reg_number", 
                    command= Reg_ex)
buttonCommit.pack()
mainloop()
```

Obstacle: How to write the print output back into the text box for user to see.

Currently it prints in terminal but I want the output returned to text area for user to see it with original text replaced with reg_ex processed text.

Please Help!

Comment: I suggest you to use another `Text`. first half for your input text and second half for your output text. Then you can use `text.insert("END", value)` to insert your input text into output one as your required format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `replace` method of the `Text` widget.

```
import tkinter as tk, re

root = tk.Tk() 

textbox = tk.Text(root, height=40, width=50)
textbox.pack()

def replace():
    textbox.replace('1.0', 'end', re.sub("\d+", '<number>', textbox.get('1.0', 'end')))
    
tk.Button(root, width=10, text="replace #'s", command=replace).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However, I would argue that it is more useful to do it this way. This version makes `replace` more dynamic and robust, allowing you to reuse it and externally control it's behavior.

```
import tkinter as tk, re

root = tk.Tk() 

textbox = tk.Text(root, height=40, width=50)
textbox.pack()

def replace(pattern, repl, count=0, flags=0, rng=('1.0', 'end')):
    textbox.replace(*rng, re.sub(pattern, repl, textbox.get(*rng), count, flags))
    
tk.Button(root, width=10, text="replace #'s", command=lambda: replace('\d+', '<number>')).pack()

root.mainloop()
```